# Make Firebase project FHIR-compatible?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, hl7-fhir, smart-on-fhir

I’m new to using [FHIR - Fast Healthcare Interoperability Resources](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/overview.html). Is it possible to make an existing Firebase project FHIR-compatible? My project uses Firebase mostly as a database for info sent to us by an application (NoSQL, BaaS). My idea is to convert the existing data into FHIR resources but I’m not sure what to do after that. How do I approach turning a Firebase project into a FHIR server?

Answer (score 1):

FHIR is a standard for data exchange.  It can be used with a wide variety of persistence technologies and varying proprietary database organizations.  Each system is unique and needs to find its own way to map its particular data structures to and from the appropriate FHIR structures.  Both the .NET and Java reference implementations include 'façade' capabilities designed to make it easier to express proprietary data structures over FHIR.  (Just search for ".NET FHIR facade" or "Java FHIR facade".)

Comment: By reference implementations, are you referring to Vonk/Firely FHIR facade and/or utilizing HAPI FHIR library [like so](https://dzone.com/articles/fhir-code-in-10min)? @Lloyd

Comment: Yes, or this: http://docs.simplifier.net/vonk/facade/facadestart.html